# Mapping HTTP routes in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have an app with orders and order details. I am trying to figure out how to best set up the architecture so I can retrieve all order details for a particular order. It would seem elegant and intuitive to have a URL structure like this:

```
http://example.com/api/orders/{orderid}/orderdetails
```

I can register a route in global.asax:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/orders/{orderid}/orderdetails",
  defaults: new { orderid = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But I can't figure out what method in the OrdersController class this maps to. What method signature does the above route expect in my controller class? For all I know, this isn't even valid, so feel free to recommend a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working with the following.

Global.asax Application_Start:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
 name: "DefaultApi",
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{orderid}/{action}"
);
```

Controller class:

```
[ActionName("OrderDetails")]
public IEnumerable<OrderDetail> GetOrderDetails(int orderId)
{
 // return data...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at amazing AttributeRouting.WebAPI package http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following page. It will be helpful
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20Web%20API

Answer (score 0):

Add System.Web.Http.WebHost dll reference into your web application. Thank You.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question. He asked which method and signature in the OrdersController class his route maps to.